# Как определить, что файл в пути не имеет папок?

Tags: php

Например, есть строка с названием файла без пути. Как оределить, что нет пути? Делаю так, не работает:

```
function get_file_info($file){
    $fileinfo = parse_url($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($fileinfo['path']);
    return array(
        'file_path' => trim($fileinfo['dirname'],'/'),
        'file_name' => $fileinfo['basename'],
        'file_ext' => $fileinfo['extension']
    );
}

$str = "owl.video.play.png";

if (get_file_info($str)["file_path"] == "") {
    echo "no path";
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотите проверить существование директории, используйте `is_dir()`, а если файла, то `is_file()`.

Comment: `strpos($filename, '/') === false`

Comment: Может достаточно просто проверить, есть ли в `$str` символ `/`? Если да, то есть

Answer (score 1):

```
echo false === strpos($filename, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) 
    ? 'No path'
    : 'Path exists';
```